# Code causes shell to restart

Tags: python, shell, matplotlib

As soon as I start running this, it causes my shell to restart. I have no idea whats going an. Im running this on mac with python 3.6.4 installed. Matplotlib is also installed.

Does anybody see what the problem could be ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

#Variablen Initialisierung 
xVals = []
yVals = []

#Diagramm anzeigen 
def makePlot():
    plt.plot(xVals,yVals)
    plt.scatter(xVals,yVals)
    plt.ylabel(yLabelText.get())
    plt.xlabel(xLabelText.get())  
    plt.title(titleText.get())
    plt.show()

#xls.Daten einlesen
def loadFile():
    global xVals
    global yVals
    xVals = [] #reset Data
    yVals = [] #reset Data
    file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    with open(file_path,'r') as csvfile:
        dataReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
        for row in dataReader:
            if len(row) < 2: #Auf validen Input pruefen
                print("Invalid Input")
                exit(-1)
            xVals.append(row[0])
            yVals.append(row[1])

root = tk.Tk(className="Diagramm-Creator Anna, Deny, Sina") #Überschrift

#Label Initalisierung             
tk.Label(root, text="Diagramm").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Titel").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(root, text="X-Achse").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Y-Achse").grid(row=3)

#Input Initalisierung
yLabelText = tk.StringVar()
xLabelText = tk.StringVar()
titleText = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = xLabelText)
e2 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = yLabelText)
e3 = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = titleText)
e3.grid(row=1, column=1)
e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)

#Buttons Initalisierung
btnOpen = tk.Button(root, text="CSV-Datei öffnen",command=loadFile)
btnPlot = tk.Button(root, text="Diagramm erstellen",command=makePlot)
btnOpen.grid(row=0,column=2)
btnPlot.grid(row=4,column=2)

#Start
root.mainloop( )
```

Comment: Any clue of the last line that get executed? Can you please also describe the precise commands and shell you use to run the code?

Comment: Do you mean root.mainloop()? I have python 3.4.6 installed and running it with IDLE. I write the code in a file and run the code through IDLE

Answer (score 0):

The only clue I have is that this piece of code:

```
    with open(file_path,'r') as csvfile:
        dataReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
        for row in dataReader:
            if len(row) < 2: #Auf validen Input pruefen
                print("Invalid Input")
                exit(-1)
```

would make you exit abruptly from execution and also from Python shell...

Maybe you want to replace the print and exit lines with an exception:

```
    with open(file_path,'r') as csvfile:
        dataReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
        for row in dataReader:
            if len(row) < 2: #Auf validen Input pruefen
                raise ValueError('Invalid Input')
```

Comment: Depends what you mean by "shell".  `exit(-1)` will certainly exit the Python REPL if you are running this code in that, but it should not cause a calling Bash process to exit, for example. (A negative exit code isn't really well-defined to the shell but it seems to get converted to an exit code of 255 like you would expect.)